# Jenkins kubernetes plugin not working

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-2

I am trying to setup Jenkins Dynamic slaves creation using jenkins-kubernetes plugin.

**My jenkins is running outside K8s Cluster.**

Link: https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin

My jenkins version is **2.60.2** and Kubernetes plugin version is **1.1.2**

I followed the steps mention on the readme and successfully setup the connection.

My setting looks like:
[image]

And connection is successful.

Then I created a job with pod template :
[image]

Here starts the problem:
**1. When I run this job initially it runs and jenkins slave container inside my pod not able to connect and throws:**

[image]

I have enabled JNLP port(50000) not sure if it is the right port even tested with random option in Jenkins nothing worked.

**2. Now I discarded this jenkins job and re run again it says:**

```
 Started by user Vaibhav Jain
[Pipeline] podTemplate
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] node
Still waiting to schedule task
Jenkins doesn’t have label defaultlabel
```

and no pod is getting started in kubernetes. **This is weird**.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. 
Need help!

Comment: Some quick questions to understand the context:
1 - can you successfully connect to k8s in the Jenkins configuration page?
2 - do you have any proxy and/or Matrix-based security enable?

Comment: 1. Yes I am able to connect, it says connection successful.
2. No, I have not enabled proxy or Matrix-based security. I am using K8s 1.6

Comment: Hi, I have a question, I setup jenkins and the slaves in different clusters. How did you do so jenkins can communicate with the other cluster?? Thanks!

Comment: @Alo you may use kubeconfig file for this.(it might be a RBAC or a ABAC)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of using certificates, I suggest you to use credentials in kubernetes, by creating a serviceAccount:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: jenkins
---
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: jenkins
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods"]
  verbs: ["create","delete","get","list","patch","update","watch"]
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods/exec"]
  verbs: ["create","delete","get","list","patch","update","watch"]
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods/log"]
  verbs: ["get","list","watch"]
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["secrets"]
  verbs: ["get"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: jenkins
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: jenkins
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: jenkins
```

and deploying jenkins using that serviceAccount:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: jenkins
  name: jenkins
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: jenkins
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: jenkins
    spec:           
      serviceAccountName: jenkins 
....
```

I show you my screenshots for Kubernetes plugin (note Jenkins tunnel for the JNLP port, 'jenkins' is the name of my kubernetes service):

[image]

[image]

For credentials:

[image]

Then fill the fileds (ID will be autogenerated, description will be shown in credentials listbox), but be sure to have created serviceAccount in kubernetes as I said before:

[image]

My instructions are for the Jenkins master inside kubernetes. If you want it outside the cluster (but slaves inside) I think you have to use simple login/password credentials.

For what concerns your last error, it seems to be a host resolution error: the slave cannot resolve your host.

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks @Nicola for the detailed answer but in that case I need to move my Jenkins into K8s which itself comes with its own challenges.
What I am planning is to run Jenkins outside K8s cluster and use K8s cluster as slaves. Any advice on this?
Also, If I switched on your approach, what would be the credential type while setting K8s plugin(picture shown above Kubernetes credentials for Jenkins) and what would be those credentials?

Comment: Thanks Nicola for your guidance, I switched to Jenkins master inside K8s, and created service account following this 
::::   https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin/tree/master/src/main/kubernetes  :::: I am deploying Jenkins as a stateful set instead of deployment but facing issues in creating PV and claiming it which results in failing of stateful-pod. Any Idea ?
can you please share your Jenkins deployment yaml file so that I can deploy and use Jenkins.

Answer (score 3):

Ok! I find the issue, I am giving container cap as 10 (in default Namespace)which is too low for my cluster. I have 15 Worker nodes cluster and when K8s master trying starting a pod it starts multiple pods at once(though terminates rest after one is scheduled) which eventually crosses the container cap limit(which was 10). I changed the CAP to 100 and now things are working as expected.

One thing which I noticed with K8s Jenkins plugins, it will not clear out the error container itself which increases the container count and leads to this problem.

Comment: it doesn't clear errored containers to avoid infinite container creation. Jenkins master logs will print warnings

Comment: it took like 2 days for me to figure out. thanks. i think this should be the accepted answer since your problem is regarding running jenkins master outside of the cluster.