# Jenkins JNLP Slave in Kubernetes (non-numeric user - jenkins)

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jnlp

I am setting up Dynamic Jenkins slaves provision in Kubernetes.
The default jenkins/jnlp-slave:alpine works fine but I see this below error in Kubernetes Agent:

> W0129 19:09:42.310410   26799 kuberuntime_container.go:191] Non-root verification doesn't support non-numeric user (jenkins)

The job is just to check the environment variables and it runs fine & gives a proper output. But why do we have this error message?

Answer (score 0):

It seems an authentication problem.
Take a look at these following:

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/45487

[Jenkins kubernetes plugin not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47870961/jenkins-kubernetes-plugin-not-working/47874390#47874390)

Hope this helps.